# Android build tools 1.1.0, unit test folder?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, robolectric, android-build, build-tools

I recently installed the latest tools from google to my android project:

```
buildscript {
      repositories {
         jcenter()
         mavenCentral()
      }
      dependencies {
         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
      }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 200
        versionName "2.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            ...
        }
        release {
            ...
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            ...
        }
        debug {
            ...
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'

    // ---- Tests with robolectric
    testCompile 'com.google.guava:guava:14.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.+'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.4'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-all:2.0.2-beta'

    // ---- Tests with Espresso
    androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0') {
        exclude module: 'hamcrest-core'
    }
    androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1'
    androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.1'
    androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.1'
    androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1') {
        exclude module: 'hamcrest-core'
    }
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.0'
    androidTestCompile('junit:junit-dep:4.10') {
        exclude module: 'hamcrest-core'
    }
}
```

Where before that I used to use `com.github.jcandksolutions.gradle:android-unit-test:2.1.1` to run my robolectric tests in the jvm.
As google says for their new build tools: "New source folders recognized as unit tests: src/test/java, src/testDebug/java, src/testMyFlavor/java etc."
But as you can see below, my test folder isn't recognised as a source folder. It worked with `com.github.jcandksolutions.gradle:android-unit-test:2.1.1`, but no more with the new build tools:

[image]

What I'm missing here? Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution which is to switch between Test Artifacts in the left corner of the IDE. On this screen only "Android Instrumentation Tests" is available because I downgraded my android tools but with tools 1.1.0+ you should see different types of test to get the IDE recognize them as source folders.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem the other day, except that I was able to run Robolectric tests ok in Android Studio, but didn't work from the command line. What worked for me is the following.

1) Run `./gradlew clean assembleDebug test` (instead of just `clean test`)

(now, it would find source from main packages, but I would get [this problem](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=144573) instead)

2) Added this to the build.gradle file: `android.sourceSets.test.java.srcDirs += "build/generated/source/r/debug"`

Comment: Now I get errors like this `com.xxx.network.requests.AuthenticateTest > callbackForNewUser FAILED java.lang.NullPointerException`. I think I'll just stick to the old android-test-plugin for now and wait for a more stable version of the gradle build tools.

Answer (score 3):

Just follow http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support to enable the experimental unit test and switch test artifact to unit tests. then your unit test folder will be recognised.

when you have more issues perhaps this will help http://nenick-android.blogspot.de/2015/02/android-studio-110-beta-4-and.html

Comment: Thank you for theses resources but I still can't get my tests working. I figured out how to "mark" the test folder as source folder in the IDE but when I run: `./gradlew clean test` I get errors like this: `error: cannot find symbol User user = UserBuilder.fromJSON(null);`.  Where my tests classes can't find packages from my main folder.

Comment: Can you update with full error? Did you add `@Config` to your tests or implemented custom runner?

Answer (score 0):

If it's any use I set up a boiler plate project allowing the use of Unit tests and Espresso tests by the use of switching build variants. You won't need the use of any third party plugins with this.

https://github.com/hitherejoe/Android-Boilerplate