# Robolectric and Android Studio 1.1.0 and library testing

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, noclassdeffounderror, robolectric

I am having trouble getting my Robolectric unit tests to run under the experimental AS 1.1 unit testing variant. The error I am getting is shown below;

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/my/app/R$string
    at com.my.app.MoneyFormatter.formatDealMessage(MoneyFormatter.java:63)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.my.app.R$string
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.robolectric.bytecode.AsmInstrumentingClassLoader.loadClass(AsmInstrumentingClassLoader.java:100)
    ... 46 more
```

I retrieve this error by executing from the command line at the root (app-name in *Snippet1*) the command;

```
./gradlew core:library:test
```

This approach works in Android Studio 1.1 without unit testing enabled and using the android gradle tooling at v1.0 (com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0).

### Project configuration

My project has a complex structure as prescribed below;

```
app-name
 |
 |->app
    |->src
       |-> androidTest // Espresso helper classes reside here
       |-> androidTestFlavour1 // Espresso int tests relating to 'flavour 1' 
       |-> androidTestFlavour2 // Espresso int tests relating to 'flavour 2'
       |-> flavour1
       |-> flavour2
       |-> main
           + AndroidManifest.xml // Manifest for apps
       |-> testFlavour1 // Robolectric unit tests for flavour 1
       |-> testFlavour2 // Robolectric unit tests for flavour 2
 |->core
       |->library
           |-> src
              |-> main // Library code resides here
                  + AndroidManifest.xml
              |-> test // Robolectric unit tests for library
 +gradle
 +gradlew
 +settings.gradle
 +local.properties
```

*Snippet 1*: Project schematic

I have followed various pieces of advice from [Pivotal Labs](http://pivotallabs.com/setting-up-robolectric-in-android-studio-1-1-on-os-x/) themselves and numerous other home-brew alternatives with no success.

What is the error saying and what do I need to change to put it right?

**Update:**
So having inspected the classpath being used to run the tests I noted the following library paths;

- /workspace/app/core/lib/build/intermediates/bundles/debug/classes.jar
- /workspace/app/core/lib/build/intermediates/classes/test/debug
- /workspace/app/core/lib/build/intermediates/dependency-cache/test/debug

Neither of these directories contain the generated `R$string.class` file hence the exception. The directory containing the generated 'R' files include the debug and release build types of the application. So;

- /workspace/app/core/lib/build/intermediates/classes/debug
- /workspace/app/core/lib/build/intermediates/classes/release

This indicates that a part of the build process is missing adding the "debug" or "release" build type resources. This also backs-up the behaviour whereby pure-Java test cases (that only rely on the classes.jar) work fine.

Comment: @EugenMartynov - i think the question is more refined now owing to your prompt to query the classpath. Have a read of my update. Is there a reason why the ````/debug```` and ````/release```` classes are not being added alongside the 'test' build type?

Comment: Just to confirm - debug folder doesn't have any classes at all?

Comment: The ````intermediates/debug```` and ````intermediates/release```` folders contain compiled java classes (.class) and the ````intermediates/bundle/debug/```` inclusion contains the ````classes.jar````. The latter is on the classpath containing just the Java classes in the project *without* those dynamically generated (such as ````R.class````) and the former is missing from the classpath when running the tests. Should the former be on the classpath is my question initially...

Comment: I have answered that question - reverting back to the working 1.0 android tools (as opposed to 1.1) adds the ````build/intermediates/classes/debug```` - this is the crux of this issue. Now how to force gradle to add this path to the classpath to prove this theory 100%?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK! I've got it working. I have added the following line to the library build gradle to forcibly add the generated "R" files onto the test classpath;

```
sourceSets {
  test.java.srcDirs += "build/generated/source/r/debug"
}
```

With this I have reached the nirvana of *Robolectric* tests with;

```
./gradlew core:lib:test
```

and *Espresso 2.0*-based integration with;

```
./gradlew connectedAndroidTest
```

Stop the clock for unit and integration test support in the IDE.... oh, what's that? 7 YEARS?! No love lost. Kudos to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28672118/1348379) that showed me how to forcibly add stuff to the test classpath.

Comment: Amazing! Glad you found the solution